# What are some technologies/biosensors for real time kinetic analysis of reactions?

Tags: biochemistry, kinetics, proteins

I am in a lab that has used [surface plasmon resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_plasmon_resonance) (SPR) and ELISA very heavily over the past few years, and we are thinking of getting a new machine. I'm wondering what other technologies exist for making similar measurements; particularly protein -protein/antibody-antiggen binding.

[Octet](http://www.fortebio.com/octet-RED96.html) in particular looks very different because rather than passing a flow of analyte over the ligand, it puts them together in a chamber, which I'm guessing allows the user to make much longer measurements, which could be really useful for measuring low affinities and low concentrations.

Also what are peoples experiences of different Biosensors?

Comment: This question is broad as many types of reactions exists.  Which specific reaction is of interest?

Comment: You need to specify what analytes you are interested and the level of accuracy you need.  Also mention what is the scale of the reactions.

Comment: Protein -protein interactions; particularly antibody -antigen. Small volumes of reactants are preferable to large, as some of the reactants are expensive, but I'd be interested in reading about similar technology for all scales